# using npm create-react-app is not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I tried to create react app with the **npm create-react-app appname** and it will return back to me the same line to type in codes.

I also tried using **npx** but it also prompt me errors.[npm create-react-app error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/laOYb.jpg)

Comment: You typed ```reach``` instead of ```react```

Answer (score 1):

It was already indicated by the people in the comments and an answer, but still, here's the issue:
When you used `npx`, you mistyped `create-react-app` as `create-reach-app`. So, run `npx create-react-app appname`. Also, if you installed node.js correctly, you might not need to include `npx` in all commands and you can simply use `create-react-app appname` and it should work absolutely fine.

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo in the **npx** command.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you two ways of solving the problem. please check and try this:)

1. create-react-app appname (type without npm)
2. npx create-react-app appname

[React website here](http://%5Bhttps://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html)